# Insert/delete operation for large data in python without merge

Tags: python, sql-server

I am quite new to python. I have a table that I want to update daily. I get a csv file with large amount of data, about 15000 entries. Each row from the csv file has to be inserted in my table. But If a specific value from the file matches the primary key of any of the rows, the I want to delete the row from the table and instead insert the corresponding row from the csv file. So for eg. if my csv file is like this:

```
001|test1|test11|test111
002|test2|test22|test222
003|test3|test33|test333
```

And in my table I have a row with `primary key column value=002`, then delete that row and insert corresponding row from the file.

I don't have an idea about how many rows I could get in that csv every day, with values matching primary key. I know this can be done with a `MERGE` query but I am not really sure if it will take a longer time than any other method. And it would also require me to create a temp table and truncate it every time. Same if I use `WHERE EXISTS`, I would need a temp table.

What is the most efficient way to do this task?

I am using Python 2.7.5 and SQL Server 2017

Comment: Why do you want to `DELETE` the row and then re-`INSERT` it? Why not `UPDATE` the row if it already exists? Then you could just do an "Upsert"

Comment: Fastest way is exactly what you have said, except use `BULK INSERT` to load the temp table, and don't forget to add a primary key on the temp table also. If you put this in a stored procedure then the creation of the temp table will be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think using merge statement is the optimal solution. Create a stage-table matching your target table, truncate it and insert the csv to the stage table. If your sqlserver instance has access to the file you can use `bulk insert` or `open rowset` to load it, othervise use python. To load staged data to target table use a `MERGE` statement.

If your table has column names Id, Col1, Col2, Col3 then something like this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable as TargetTable USING
(
SELECT
Id,Col1,Col2,Col3
FROM dbo.stage_MyTable
) as SourceTable
ON TargetTable.Id = SourceTable.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  Col1 = SourceTable.Col1,
  Col2 = SourceTable.Col2,
  Col3 = SourceTable.Col3
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
(Id,Col1, Col2,Col3)
VALUES 
(SourceTable.Id,SourceTable.Col1, SourceTable.Col2,SourceTable.Col3)
;
```

The benefit of this approach is that the query will be executed as a single transaction so if there are duplicate rows or similar the table status will be rolled back to previous state.